# NTP - No system peer entry ("*") found

Tags: networking, 18.04, ntp

I have NTP setup on two Ubuntu 18.04 VM's but my monitoring solution has alerted me only one is getting proper NTP. They are on two different networks, so that may have something to do with it, but both have internet connectivity.

The one that isn't working shows the following:

```
 sudo ntpq -c lpeer
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
 0.ubuntu.pool.n .POOL.          16 p    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
 1.ubuntu.pool.n .POOL.          16 p    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
 2.ubuntu.pool.n .POOL.          16 p    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
 3.ubuntu.pool.n .POOL.          16 p    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
 ntp.ubuntu.com  .POOL.          16 p    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
```

The working one shows:

```
 sudo ntpq -c lpeer
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
 0.ubuntu.pool.n .POOL.          16 p    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
 1.ubuntu.pool.n .POOL.          16 p    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
 2.ubuntu.pool.n .POOL.          16 p    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
 3.ubuntu.pool.n .POOL.          16 p    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
 ntp.ubuntu.com  .POOL.          16 p    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
+time.cloudflare 10.28.8.252      3 u   22 1024  377   30.040    3.941   1.989
+144.172.126.201 129.7.1.66       2 u  917 1024  377   83.911    6.136   5.755
*ntp2.wiktel.com .GPS.            1 u  737 1024  377   72.007    1.744   5.763
-23.129.64.159   74.6.168.72      3 u 1903 1024  372   30.086    7.653   1.957
-ntp.speculation 164.67.62.194    2 u  190 1024  357   56.998    6.365   1.344
```

They were setup the same was as far as I know, `apt install ntp` and that's it, but I can't get the one to show properly! Any ideas what could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

First two possibilities:

1. Broken DNS resolution.  Run `host ntp.ubuntu.com` (or `dig`, or `nslookup` - whichever you have installed) from the non-working system to find out if they return IP addresses.
2. Firewall blocking network connectivity.  If you can't get to a pool host over UDP port 123, NTP will not function.

As always, checking `/var/log/syslog` for messages from `ntpd` or using `systemctl status ntp` might offer some useful hints as to which one is more likely.

Comment: Too bad I'm laid off lol, I'll check when  back at work!

Comment: Sorry to hear that - hope things return to usual for you soon!